# Maven can not build spring boot app after properties file has been changed (Failed to parse configuration class)

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-boot

I'm building a small web application using Spring Boot. And I get an error, after try running the application.
It worked well, but then I changed some values in properties file and now Maven fails to build the app. It fails running it with IntelliJ IDEA and with command line as well. I have searched a lot here, but couldn't find anything useful for my case...

Here is the stack trace:

```
2019-01-27 18:10:57.773  INFO 2144 --- [           main] c.f.FriendlyFireChessApplication         : Starting FriendlyFireChessApplication on DESKTOP-PC4K83Q with PID 2144 (C:\Users\Svidic\IdeaProjects\friendly-fire-chess\target\classes started by Svidic in C:\Users\Svidic\IdeaProjects\friendly-fire-chess)
2019-01-27 18:10:57.781  INFO 2144 --- [           main] c.f.FriendlyFireChessApplication         : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
2019-01-27 18:10:57.922  INFO 2144 --- [           main] s.c.a.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext : Refreshing org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext@21507a04: startup date [Sun Jan 27 18:10:57 EET 2019]; root of context hierarchy
2019-01-27 18:10:58.515  WARN 2144 --- [           main] s.c.a.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Failed to parse configuration class [com.ffirechess.FriendlyFireChessApplication]; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to introspect annotated methods on class org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.SpringBootServletInitializer
2019-01-27 18:10:58.536 ERROR 2144 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed

org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Failed to parse configuration class [com.ffirechess.FriendlyFireChessApplication]; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to introspect annotated methods on class org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.SpringBootServletInitializer
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.parse(ConfigurationClassParser.java:184) ~[spring-context-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.processConfigBeanDefinitions(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:316) ~[spring-context-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.postProcessBeanDefinitionRegistry(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:233) ~[spring-context-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanDefinitionRegistryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:271) ~[spring-context-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:91) ~[spring-context-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:694) ~[spring-context-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:532) ~[spring-context-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:762) [spring-boot-2.0.4.RELEASE.jar:2.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:398) [spring-boot-2.0.4.RELEASE.jar:2.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:330) [spring-boot-2.0.4.RELEASE.jar:2.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1258) [spring-boot-2.0.4.RELEASE.jar:2.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1246) [spring-boot-2.0.4.RELEASE.jar:2.0.4.RELEASE]
    at com.ffirechess.FriendlyFireChessApplication.main(FriendlyFireChessApplication.java:22) [classes/:na]
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to introspect annotated methods on class org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.SpringBootServletInitializer
    at org.springframework.core.type.StandardAnnotationMetadata.getAnnotatedMethods(StandardAnnotationMetadata.java:169) ~[spring-core-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.retrieveBeanMethodMetadata(ConfigurationClassParser.java:393) ~[spring-context-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.doProcessConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassParser.java:318) ~[spring-context-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.processConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassParser.java:245) ~[spring-context-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.parse(ConfigurationClassParser.java:202) ~[spring-context-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.parse(ConfigurationClassParser.java:170) ~[spring-context-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
    ... 12 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/servlet/ServletContext
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_144]
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2701) ~[na:1.8.0_144]
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods(Class.java:1975) ~[na:1.8.0_144]
    at org.springframework.core.type.StandardAnnotationMetadata.getAnnotatedMethods(StandardAnnotationMetadata.java:158) ~[spring-core-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
    ... 17 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.servlet.ServletContext
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381) ~[na:1.8.0_144]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424) ~[na:1.8.0_144]
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:335) ~[na:1.8.0_144]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357) ~[na:1.8.0_144]
    ... 21 common frames omitted


Process finished with exit code 1
```

pom.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.ffc</groupId>
    <artifactId>friendly-fire-chess</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>

    <name>friendly-fire-chess</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.4.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-dataformat-xml</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-starter-data-jpa -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/mysql/mysql-connector-java -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-starter-security -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.jsonwebtoken</groupId>
            <artifactId>jjwt</artifactId>
            <version>0.9.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>



    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>


</project>
```

property file, which has been changed:

```
spring.datasource.username='username'
spring.datasource.password='Password,111'
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/users
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
tokenSecret=1515sthsrtjmku
server.servlet.context-path=/friendly-fire-chess
```

UPDATE:
Backing up entire project from the local history to the last correct state solved the issue. But I still don't know what caused the failure of building the app.

UPDATE 2:
Ok, I figured it out. It failed because there was no user in my local MySQL instance which would correspond to the values I've provided in   application.properties. Once I created such user everything works fine.

UPDATE 3:
The real reason was not in MySQL. The code and dependencies were right as well. The issue was in my run configuration. I have fixed it by adding "spring-boot:run" to Command line parameter of run configuration.
Hope it helps someone.

Comment: Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.servlet.ServletContext
seems to be missing in your classpath,  try mvn clean install

Comment: i've posted the anwser below

Answer (score 4):

the issue is that you have a provided dependency

```
 <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
            ***<scope>provided</scope>*** <!--to be removed-->
        </dependency>
```

it's coming with             spring-boot-starter-web
no need to provided it unless you are using tomcat and in this case you should excluded it from    spring-boot-starter-web

-- update 
if you are using tomcat so in this case you need to exclude the tomcat dependency packaged in spring-boot-starter-web as below

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    <!--add this exclusion to your pom -->
    <exclusions>
        **<exclusion>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
        </exclusion>**
    </exclusions>
</dependency>
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
 </dependency>
```

Comment: Yes, I'm using tomcat-9. Not sure what do you mean by "you should excluded it from spring-boot-starter-web".  What should I exclude from here:  `<dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>`

Comment: Does not work. As I have mentioned everything worked well before I changed `spring.datasource.username` and  `spring.datasource.password` in application.properties. I did not change the code or pom.xml. So I gues issue is somewhere in  application.properties.

Comment: the stack trace is not related to a configuration issue but rather a build issue, check your source control or local history to identify the changes

Comment: The only changes after last successfull build (that was made today) are the values of top 2 lines in application.properties. After that something went wrong.

Comment: After backing up entire project from the local history it works again! @CodeIsLife thanks for your help!